# What is Difference between Daily Device Installs and Daily user Installs of Google Android console?

Tags: android

Please help me understanding the difference between Daily device installs and Daily user installs

Comment: maybe users can have multiple devices?

Answer (score 6):

Daily user installs means how many people install your app. Daily device installs means how many devices your app is installed on. A user may have one or more devices (two phones, one phone, one tablet, etc).

Comment: Which of them is counted as total number of installs shown on the Play Store page? I believe it should be `Device installs`.

Answer (score 1):

User Install represents number of people that download (email ID for example).

Device Install represents number of devices where app is downloaded (user may have one or more devices).

So it's possible to have more device installs than user installs.

For monetization, we need consider "Installs by User" only.